# perform action on clearing app from taskbar android programmatically

Tags: android, background, android-lifecycle

i want to hit an API when app is closed. I have done the api work in onDestroy method. this works when i exit app by backpress. but in case when i directly clear app from Taskbar without backpress, then method don't run. I am now looking for method which helps me to perform action when i clear app from taskbar. I hope you guys help. Thanks for your support

here is my code

```
                                     override fun onBackPressed() {
                                         logout2()
                                         super.onBackPressed()
                                     }

                                     override fun onDestroy() {
                                         logout2()
                                         super.onDestroy()
                                     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your Manifest file, keep flag stopWithTask as false for Service. Like:

```
 <service
    android:name="com.myapp.MyService"
    android:stopWithTask="false" />
```

MyService.java

```
public class MyService extends AbstractService {

    @Override
    public void onStartService() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "My network services", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, "AppName", "Message", pendingIntent);
        startForeground(MY_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);  
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onTaskRemoved called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println("onTaskRemoved called");
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
}
```

AbstractService.java is custom class that extends Sevrice:

```
public abstract class AbstractService extends Service {

    protected final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        onStartService();
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate(): Service Started.");
    }

    @Override
    public final int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStarCommand(): Received id " + startId + ": " + intent);
        return START_STICKY; // run until explicitly stopped.
    }

    @Override
    public final IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return m_messenger.getBinder();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        onStopService();
        Log.i(TAG, "Service Stopped.");
    }    

    public abstract void onStartService();
    public abstract void onStopService();
    public abstract void onReceiveMessage(Message msg);

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "AS onTaskRemoved called", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is  return m_messenger.getBinder() here, from where it is comming. @Urvish Jani